Can Intents Operate on Upgrades and Deployments?
Lets say you want to upgrade your smart contract using the proxy upgrade pattern.
Just like how intents can say "only do this tx if it meets this criteria"
Can we use intents to say "only do the upgrade if it meets this criteria"
Thx
